# Merging or appending array of objects in different object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am using angularjs where I have a $scope.var1 ={a:10, b:20, c:30}; in which I want to append another value(s) which is infact an array of objects i.e. $scope.myobjects=[{m:10, n:30}, {x:6, y:8}, ....]; after appending this value my $scope.var1 should look like, $scope.var1={a:10, b:20, c:30, m:10, n:30, x:6, y:8};
any idea please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
obj ={a:10, b:20, c:30}; 
arr=[{m:10, n:30}, {x:6, y:8}];
arr.forEach(function(a){
Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key){
obj[key]=a[key];
})
})
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array and use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

> The **`Object.assign()`** method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

If not on the user agent available, like on IE, you could use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill).

```js
var target = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 };
    objects = [{ m: 10, n: 30 }, { x: 6, y: 8 }];

objects.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.assign(target, o);
});

console.log(target);
```

Comment: Note: Object.assign is not support in all browsers, unless you are using babel with the https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-assign/

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.assign.apply(null, [$scope.var1].concat($scope.myobjects))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```js
var var1 = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 };
    myobjects = [{ m: 10, n: 30 }, { x: 6, y: 8 }];

myobjects.forEach(function (o) {
    for (var p in o) {var1[p] = o[p]};
});

console.log(var1);
```

Note that this code simply add/update properties based on source object

Comment: just to edit the above code/question, my objects are like this below var1 = [{ a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 }];
    myobjects = [{ m: 10, n: 30 }, { x: 6, y: 8 }]; and when I am trying the above method var1 is always the same, no changes.

Comment: in case var1 is just 1 array of object you can replace code to this
`myobjects.forEach(function (o) {
        for (var p in o) {var1[0][p] = o[p]};
    });
var1 = var1[0];`